# Rails search a model based on multiple parameters using a form

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, search, parameters

So... I've been working on creating a search form for a rails application. I've gone through the railscast episodes 37, 111, and 112.

While the simple text search with a text input field works. I need to be able to define more parameters to refine the search.

I've found a few other methods, some using scopes...I keep running into issues getting any of these working in my application....

What I have right now is a simple form defined on my home index that points at my assets index:

```
<% form_tag assets_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= collection_select(:type_id, :type_id, Type.where("type_for = 'asset'"), :id, :name) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :search => nil %>
<% end %>
```

my asset.rb model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :children_assets, :class_name => "Asset"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, :join_table => "assets_groups"

  belongs_to :parent_asset, 
         :class_name => "Asset", 
         :foreign_key => "parent_asset_id"

  belongs_to :asset_type, 
         :class_name => "Type", 
         :conditions => "type_for = 'asset'"

  belongs_to :asset_status, 
         :class_name => "Status", 
         :conditions => "status_for = 'asset'"

  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :funding_source

  has_many :transactions

  def self.search(search)
      if search
        find(:all, :conditions => ['nmc_name LIKE ? AND type_id = ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}"])
      else
        find(:all)
      end
    end

  end
```

in the asset_controller.rb

```
def index
  unless params[:search].nil?
    @title = "Assets"
    @search = params[:search]
    @assets = Asset.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
  else
    @title = "Assets"
    @assets = Asset.where('').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
  end

end
```

I just dont understand what it is that I'm not seeing here. I can run a similar mysql query and get the result I want. I just dont know how to format this in rails...

Any guidance on this would be amazing right now. Thanks!

Comment: Looks okay to me - what are the problems you're receiving? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: At a glance, shouldn't the `self.search` method be using an `OR` clause in the SQL rather than an `AND`? I'm assuming that the user will be searching for text, and that the `type_id` field is going to be a simple integer? If so, then this will never return results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you're trying to search for a specific type of asset, but your `search` method in the `Asset` model is only using one of the user supplied parameters.

Judging by the form you're using, your controller will be receiving the params

```
params = {
  search: 'Search Text',
  type_id: 1
}
```

In your controller, you're only using search, so I'd change your method to include this:

```
@assets = Asset.search(params[:search], params[:type_id]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

Then amend the `Assets` model to use it

```
def self.search(search, type_id)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['nmc_name LIKE ? AND type_id = ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{type_id}"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks PaRee, you're absolutely correct and I actually happened to finally notice that last night. I also had an issue in my sql query where my second parameter type_id need to be "#{type_id}" instead since I'm not needing to parse that column for the value. its just needs to be which ever integer the user selects.

Now what I'm going to have to figure out is how to send a collection_select as just an integer.. since it why I have it seems to include type_id=>8 into the parameters passed...


Thanks again for the help!